# custom function giving error too many indices for tensor of dimension 1

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I am calculating loss for multiclass(7) classification program using pytorch.

```
class AFL(nn.Module):
   
    def __init__(self, delta=0.7, gamma=2., epsilon=1e-07):
        super(AFL, self).__init__()
        self.delta = delta
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.epsilon = epsilon

    def forward(self, y_pred, y_true):
        #y_pred=y_pred.size()[1]
        print(y_pred.shape) #[32,7]
        print(y_true.shape) #[32]
        y_pred = torch.clamp(y_pred, self.epsilon, 1. - self.epsilon)
        cross_entropy = np.empty(y_pred.shape)
        for i in range(len(y_pred)):
            for j in range(len(y_pred[i])):
                cross_entropy[i][j] = -y_true * torch.log(y_pred[i][j])
        #cross_entropy = -y_true * torch.log(y_pred[0][0]) #here i want to calculate cross_entropy for for each class
        
    # Calculate losses separately for each class, only suppressing background class
        back_ce = torch.pow(1 - y_pred[:,0], self.gamma) * cross_entropy[:,0]
        back_ce =  (1 - self.delta) * back_ce

        fore_ce = cross_entropy[:,1,:,:]
        fore_ce = self.delta * fore_ce

        loss = torch.mean(torch.sum(torch.stack([back_ce, fore_ce], axis=-1), axis=-1))
        return loss
```

I want to calculate back_ce for each class separately , but getting error as;

```
 back_ce = torch.pow(1 - y_pred[:,0], self.gamma) * cross_entropy[:,0]
IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1
```

Can anyone please tell where i am doing wrong. size of y_pred and y_true is mentioned.

Comment: according to the shapes provided, ``cross_entropy``` will be a 1-D tensor  but u trying to read in 2-D.

Comment: @NelsonakaSpOOKY trying to convert it to 2-D . now it is giving ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars. added the edit code. please check

Comment: You should also use `cross_entropy[i][j] = -y_true[i] * torch.log(y_pred[i][j])` assuming you are doing a point wise multiplication. But instead of doing all this you can use built-in `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`.

you will also get an error on this line `fore_ce = cross_entropy[:,1,:,:]` becuase u are indexing 4 dimensions. If you could tell me the contents of `y_pred` and `y_true` then may be I can tell you more about it. what does it contain? does it contain class-indices or probabilities. have u applied softmax beforehand?

Comment: @NelsonakaSpOOKY hii, u are right,i got error in fore_ce. even in back_ce  also something like this :cross_entropy[:,0,:,:] is used. my y_pred contains the probabilities like this for one row -0.0637, -0.1098,  0.0843, -0.1123, -0.0091,  0.0213,  0.0375] and y_true contains class number[5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 2].  for your refernce i am adding the github link which i am following .https://github.com/oikosohn/compound-loss-pytorch/blob/main/unified_focal_loss_pytorch.py please look into it. i am using asymmeticfocalloss function.

Comment: and the equation i am using is equation number 20 form this pdf https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0895611121001750?token=B7E5A3B9B3CFED858CE669AF8F11979F4BA3457CF5739AEE212B54EDE0E810FB110E0C793933417AA2BE71F729828453&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20230124191528. please help me where i am doing wrong

Comment: The equation (20) talks about a "rare class" . The github code u provided has calculated the AFL loss considering that there are only two classes (binary) and as I understand they have applied the loss considering that the "background" is *not* the "rare class".  However you are talking about multi-class, in that case the formula u found on github is not going to work as it is.

Comment: As a phd researcher myself, I would like to help you on this topic, but its jus too much to write on stackoverflow. Plus, I cant give u the exact formula until I understand which classes are u considering as "rare" in ur formulation. However, I can help you if u could arrange some online meet (like google meet) if u r interested. It would be much convenient.

Comment: @NelsonakaSpOOKY hii,yess we can connect over meet. I will share you the link. Can I have your contact details please? And about dataset I am using HAM10000 dataset for this program. This is having 7 classes out of which 4 classes are rare class(akiec,bkl,df,vasc). Dataset link: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kmader/skin-cancer-mnist-ham10000:

Comment: mail: nelson.navnel@gmail.com

Comment: available in the evening after 4pm IST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the AFL for multi-class with multiple common and rare classes.

```
class AsymmetricFocalLoss(nn.Module):
    """For Imbalanced datasets
    Parameters
    ----------
    delta : float, optional
        controls weight given to false positive and false negatives, by default 0.25
    gamma : float, optional
        Focal Tversky loss' focal parameter controls degree of down-weighting of easy examples, by default 2.0
    epsilon : float, optional
        clip values to prevent division by zero error
    common : list, required
        a list of common class indices
    rare : list, required
        a list of rare class indices
    """
    def __init__(self, common, rare, delta=0.7, gamma=2., epsilon=1e-07):
        super(AsymmetricFocalLoss, self).__init__()
        self.delta = delta
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.common = common
        self.rare = rare

    def forward(self, y_pred, y_labels):
        # assume y_pred contain probabilities (batch_size_ n_class)
        # y_labels contain integer class lables (batch_size, )

        # convert one-hot
        y_true = torch.zeros_like(y_pred)
        for i,j in enumerate(y_labels):y_true[i, j]=1

        # clamp
        y_pred = torch.clamp(y_pred, self.epsilon, 1. - self.epsilon)
        cross_entropy = -y_true * torch.log(y_pred)
        #print(f'{cross_entropy.shape=}\n{cross_entropy=}')
    
        # Calculate losses separately for each class,
        all_ce=[]

        for c in self.common:
            back_ce = (1 - self.delta) * (torch.pow(1 - y_pred[:,c], self.gamma) * cross_entropy[:,c])
            all_ce.append(back_ce)

        for r in self.rare:
            fore_ce=self.delta * cross_entropy[:,r]
            all_ce.append(fore_ce)

        loss_stack = torch.stack(all_ce, axis=-1)
        #print(f'{loss_stack.shape=}\n{loss_stack=}')

        loss_sum=torch.sum(loss_stack, axis=-1)
        #print(f'{loss_sum.shape=}\n{loss_sum=}')

        loss = torch.mean(loss_sum)

        return loss
```

To use this,

```
batch_size = 5
n_class = 7

y_pred = torch.softmax( torch.rand((batch_size, n_class)), dim=-1)
y_labels = torch.randint(0, n_class, size=(batch_size,))
print(f'{y_pred=}\n{y_labels=}')

lossF = AsymmetricFocalLoss(common = [0,2,4,6], rare = [1,3,5])
loss = lossF(y_pred, y_labels)

print(f'{loss=}')
```

output:

```
"""
y_pred=tensor([[0.1955, 0.1455, 0.0976, 0.1869, 0.1043, 0.1173, 0.1529],
        [0.1613, 0.1635, 0.1121, 0.1290, 0.1571, 0.0993, 0.1777],
        [0.0978, 0.1340, 0.1025, 0.1993, 0.2197, 0.1041, 0.1425],
        [0.1371, 0.1113, 0.1771, 0.1560, 0.0897, 0.1554, 0.1734],
        [0.1960, 0.1890, 0.1403, 0.1076, 0.1714, 0.1079, 0.0878]])
y_labels=tensor([0, 3, 2, 5, 3])
loss=tensor(1.0328)
"""
```